# Equations in a quadratic field

Tags: equation-solving

I would like to solve a system of equations in a quadratic field, meaning that each variable $x$ of my system can be written $a + b  \sqrt{d}$, where $d$ is a fixed value.

Suppose for example that I take $d=5$ and consider the following system (simplified for the example, the real case has more variables):

```
Reduce[{(5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + x2 Sqrt[5])^2 + (-1 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + x2 Sqrt[5])^2 == 3 + 5 Sqrt[5] && 
  (1 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + x2 Sqrt[5]) + (-5 + 6 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + x2 Sqrt[5]) == 0}, 
     {x1, x2, x3, x4}, Integers]
```

My question is the following:
Should I split the each equation into two equations (one for the integral part and one for the part with $\sqrt{5}$)? Or will *Mathematica* do that automatically to solve the equation?

Comment: Your code immediately returns `False`. Something is wrong with the conditions you specified. I would start from fixing that first.

Comment: The example system is inconsistent.  The first is the product of two linear factors, parallel to and distinct from the second.

Comment: As I said, it is a minimal example and the fact that the system has a solution or not does not change my question about the splitting. By the way, I my application I hope that the system has no solution.

Comment: But the `Reduce` command returns the correct answer in this example.  No need to change it.  Do you have an example where `Reduce` does not work and you need help?  -- Site usage tip: If you include @user in your response, where "user" is someone site name, the user will be notified of the reply.  Author's of posts are always notified.

Comment: @MichaelE2: The example here is correct but in my real applications the system has more equations and since it is non linear it takes quite a lot of time to run. Hence, I'm wondering if I have to split the equations in order to reduce computation time.

Comment: Not sure what will be done under the hood. Separating might not be a bad idea in any case. Could be done as `polys = {(5 + 2 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + Sqrt[5] x2)^2 + (-1 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + 
       Sqrt[5] x2)^2 - (3 + 
      5 Sqrt[5]), (1 + 3 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + Sqrt[5] x2) + (-5 + 
       6 Sqrt[5]) (x1 + Sqrt[5] x2)};
xpolys = Flatten[CoefficientList[polys, Sqrt[5]]]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks!